# Save multiple local storage input

Tags: javascript, html, json

i hope your day is doing well,i m trying to save multiple input  by parsing localStorage into JSON with the'for' loop for this purpose but it saved nothing  ,the error in CONSOLE:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token J in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>"
```

Code around line 32:

```
 <script>   

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    //line 32 bellow 

    var values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('emploi') || '{}');              
    // parse stored JSON if it exists otherwise an empty object 

      var inputs = document.getElementsByName('emploi');
      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var x = inputs[i];
        x.value = values[i] || '';// stored value if it exists or empty string

        x.onchange = function() {
          // assign value to the object above
          values[i] = this.value;
          // store updated version of object
          localStorage.setItem('emploi', JSON.stringify(values));
        }
      }
    });

  </script>
           <!--Html-->
           <!--SALE-->
           <input type="text"  name='emploi' placeholder='Sale'>
           <!--les prof-->
           <input type="text"  name='emploi' placeholder='Professeur'>
           <!--les classes-->
           <input type="text"  name='emploi' placeholder='Class'>
```

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('emploi')` contains some text that starts with a "J". This is not valid JSON, so the parsing fails. You may wrap it in a try-catch block to catch these errors and initialize `values` to an empty object as fallback.

Comment: i handle it but another error come out ,Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Comment: line :     x.value = values[i] || '';// stored value if it exists or empty string

Comment: Now `values` is undefined and you're trying to access `values[0]` which is not possible

Answer (score 0):

The localStorage content you're parsing is not valid JSON but a string starting with a "J".

To safely parse the localStorage content as JSON and use an empty object as fallback, wrap the parsing in a try-catch block:

```
var values = {};
try {
    values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('emploi') || '{}');        
} catch (ex) {
    console.warn('LocalStorage did not contain valid json, continuing with empty values object: ', ex);
}
```

Comment: really appreciate that i got it,but the input is going empty after any refreshing !!!!!